# Can‘t boot back to macOS after running partition utility under Windows

Tags: macos, bootcamp

After I downloaded an app to help me partition stuff on windows, I tried to boot back into mac os but the disk didn't show up so I can't get back into it
[image]

Comment: see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202796

Comment: Never let Windows touch the partitioning. It simply doesn't understand how it's being fooled into thinking it's in charge. How current is your backup?

Comment: Just got the computer so haven't backed it up yet

Comment: What model/year Mac? You have to understand this question in one form or another has been asked and answered so many times that often the question gets closed. Erasing the Mac and starting over may be a good option. Otherwise, can you boot to [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314), open a  Terminal window and post the output from `diskutil list /dev/disk0` and `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`?

Comment: 2nd @DavidAnderson. I'd recommend starting over, use macOS recovery to wipe the entire hard drive and reinstall macOS. Then install Windows using BootCamp. If you need to adjust the partitions, do it only from the macOS side. Most importantly, always keep a current back up when modifying partitions.